# HTML/CSS: Could this be achieved with a list or table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am trying to make a list of hyperlinked images, one for each color in a catalog. I want the layout to look like this:

[image: Colors]

Only, I will probably only do 5 or 6 wide by however many tall. The images to be added will be generated from the result of a MySQL query, so it won't be static. It's easy enough to make a list element like this with a foreach statement:

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {

  echo '<li><a href="?color='.$value.'"><img src="'.$value.'.jpg" /></a></li>';

}
```

... the above as a brief example. However, if this can not be achieved with a list, how would I do this with a table, not knowing how many results I will have ahead of time, therefore not knowing how many `<td>`'s and `<tr>`'s I'll need?

Thanks!

Comment: are you talking about something like this? http://1054.fleeceitout.com/council

Comment: @Deryck - Pretty much, just much smaller scale, and up to 20+ elements (colors)

Comment: You only need `<table>` if you can answer the following question with yes: Do I want to show tabular data? For all other purposes: 1999 called and wants its `<table>`s for layout purposes back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use `<div>` tag instead?

foreach ($result as $key => $value) {

```
  echo "<div class='some-class'>
           <a href='....?color=$value'><img src='$value.jpg' /></a>
        </div>";
```

}

..and then apply css and float it so it will nicely fill the parent container? I.e:

div.some-class {
....
....
float:left;
}

Answer (score 2):

Use div or li and simply `float:left`

Also, you can count your results returned by the DB and therefore calculate how many tr/td's you need, so not knowing how much results there will be before generating the table isn't really true.

Comment: `display:inline-block; list-style: none;`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `display: inline-block` like this:

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    echo <<<CODE
    <li style="display: inline-block">
        <a href="?color=$value">
            <img src="$value.jpg" />
        </a>
    </li>
CODE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers, I would recommend you use a list as well, but if you must use a table then use the following code

```
<?php
$noPerRow = 10; //adjust this to your layout
if ($result){?>
  <table>
    <tr>
      $c = 0;       
      foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        $c++;
        echo '<td><a href="?color='.$value.'"><img src="'.$value.'.jpg" /></a></td>';
        if ($c % $noPerRow == 0){
            echo '</tr><tr>';
        }
      }
      //tidy up last row
      while ($c % $noPerRow != 0){
        echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        $c++;
      }
      ?>
      </tr></table><?php

}
?>
```